# Updating detached entities with modified child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

How can the child collections of an entity be updated when they are in a detached state? I have a many-to-many relationship between `Groups` and `Users`. When the user edits a group, on post-back I get a list of User IDs to either add or remove from the group. The problem is that when `viewModel.Group` is detached, changes to the child collection don't get reflected when the entity is reattached and saved. Here is the code...

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (viewModel.SelectedUserIDs != null)
    {
        foreach (var id in viewModel.SelectedUserIDs)
        {
            var user = _userRepo.GetUser(id);
            viewModel.Group.Users.Add(user);
        }
    }
    _groupRepo.SaveGroup(viewModel.Group);
}
```

SaveGroup Method

```
if (group.GroupID <= 0)
{
   Context.Groups.Add(group);
}
else if (Context.Entry(group).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
{
    Context.Groups.Attach(group);
    Context.Entry(group).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
}

Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Two things I've tried are reattaching the entity right away and making changes

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    _groupRepo.Attach(viewModel.Group);
    if (viewModel.SelectedUserIDs != null)
    {
...
```

But the same problem happens. When the entity is saved, the child collection reverts back to it's original state.

The only workaround I found was to get a fresh entity and modify the fresh entity's collection which will persist the changes as expected, but using this way forces me to copy property changes from `viewModel.Group` to `freshGroup`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var freshGroup = _groupRepo.GetGroup(viewModel.Group.GroupID);
    if (viewModel.SelectedUserIDs != null)
    {
        //make child collection changes to 'freshGroup'
        //copy properties from 'viewModel.Group' to 'freshGroup'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to manually set each item's entity state:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You need to do this on child entities as well.